# Set Variable in one line Batch

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

```
set var1=Demo
set var2=%var1%
echo %var2%
rem Output:Demo
```

Why does `set var2` below not work if in one line with `set var1`?

```
set var1=& set var2=
set var1=Demo& set var2=%var1%
echo %var2%
rem output:%var1%
```

How can I `set var2` from `var1` in one line?

**Update** --- (04/04/2024)

simples code from [Neil](https://superuser.com/users/22383/neil)

```
@echo off
set var1=Demo& call set var2=%%var1%%
echo %var2%& pause
```

and with delayed on from [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var1=Demo& set var2=!var1!
echo %var2%& pause
```

Both work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why doesn't `set var2` work if in one line with `set var1`?

As [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) points out:

> The variable substitution is done on the whole command-line before the line is executed. At that time, the `var1` variable is not yet defined.

You can get around this limitation using delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var1=Demo & set var2=!var1!
echo %var2%
endlocal
```

Example:

```
F:\test>test
Demo
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [parsing - How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [Endlocal - Local environment variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [Setlocal - Local variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)

Comment: Thanks. So. No other way except with delayed on ?

Comment: No other way ...

Comment: I like ss64.com website. I copy most menus guide to excel and create powershell script with module ImportExcel to open each guide of ss64 though Powershell

Answer (score 3):

The variable substitution is done on the whole command-line
before the line is executed.
At that time, the `var1` variable is not yet defined.

The rules for an undefined variable substitution are:

- If the variable is entered interactively, no substitution is done
  and the text stays as `%var1%`
- If used in a batch file, the variable is replaced by a null string.

You need to break this one-liner into two lines in order for `var1`
to have a value. Or see answer by @DavidPostill.

Comment: Wrong. Delayed expansion will fix the one liner

Comment: @DavidPostill: Not wrong if it explains the problem, you even quoted me. But why downvote me? I added a pointer to your answer.